# Importance of compactness in Rudin problem.

Tags: real-analysis

Okay the problem goes like this:

> Suppose X, Y, Z are metric spaces, and Y is compact. Let $f$ map X into Y, let g be a continuous one-to-one mapping of Y into Z, and put $h(x)=g(f(x))$ for $x\in X$.
>
> > Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous if h is uniformly continuous. *Hint* : $g^{-1}$ has compact domain $g(Y)$, and $f(x)=g^{-1}(h(x))$. Prove also that $f$ is continuous if h is continuous.
>
> Show (by modifying Example 4.21, or by finding a different example) that the compactness of Y cannot be ommited from the hypotheses, even when X and Z are compact.

The problem is in general I cannot seem to understand why Y needs to be compact. I know does because I found a counter example namely:

---

Let $X=[0,1]$, $Y=[0,2\pi)$, and $Z=${$(x_r,y_r)\in \mathbb{R^2}:x^2+y^2=1 $}. If $f:X\to Y$ where, $f(x)=2\pi x$ for all $x\in X$ except for $x=1$ ,where $f(1)=0$, then $f$ discontinuous at $x=1$. Also if $g:Y\to Z$, where $g(y)=(\cos{y},\sin{y})$ then $g$ is continuous and injective, and the mapping $h=g\circ f$ is continuous.

---

But as far as why $Y$ must be compact in general for $f$ to be continuous (when $h$ and $g$ are continuous of course), I am sort of stuck.

### Specific questions

- Might I need to use the compactness of $Y$ to show that for every open set $U\subset Y$ the set $h^{-1}\circ g(U)$ is open? If so please point me in some direction as to how to use compactness for that.

Comment: I think that your kind of answer is what Rudin had in mind given the phrasing of the question.  In particular, you are to show that the hypothesis of the compactness of $Y$ cannot *simply* be omitted.  This is **not** to say that there is no weaker condition on $Y$ than compactness that would make the statement true.